# iOS CallKit: CXProviderConfiguration localizeName is deprecated

Tags: swift, callkit

Currently, CXProviderConfiguration localizeName is deprecated.
https://developer.apple.com/documentation/callkit/cxproviderconfiguration

```
let configuration = CXProviderConfiguration(localizedName: "Call")
=> 'init(localizedName:)' was deprecated in iOS 14.0
```

How can I set its localizeName now?
I want to show the name("Call") in the right-bottom.

[image]

Comment: Can you better explain what you're trying to achieve? The localized name you're talking about is only the name of the CXProvider and it's not displayed in the UI.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If I understood correctly your question, you want to display a custom string below the button with your app icon in the CallKit UI.

Contrary to what I thought and wrote in the comment, the `localizedName` of `CXProviderConfiguration`, prior to iOS 14 was used as the label of the button mentioned above.

On iOS 14 and above, instead, is the **Product Name** that's used for that purpose. You can find it in the build settings of your target, and by default, it's equal to your target name. Keep in mind that it's also the string displayed below your app icon on the home screen.

Comment: Thanks! I completely solved it.

I didn't set "Display Name" in my Xcode... 
By the way, I cannot find its specification in the document.

Comment: You're welcome! I can't find it too in the documentation, I just find it out by doing some tests. I think that the reasoning behind it is that they don't want the developers to use a name different from the app name, because this would confuse the user.